# Why 独 〔獨〕 dú is alone?

Tags: glyph-origin

I am learning the word 独 dú alone.

Dog plus Insect become alone? Any ancient history or story behind this?

Comment: If you're planning to learn Chinese Characters through exploring character structure, Simplified Chinese is going to make life very difficult for you.

Comment: Added 〔獨〕. I think this is traditional character. Will this traditional character helps? Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 「虫」 (*venomous snake; insect*) in the character, that is an abbreviation used in Simplified Chinese. The orthodox character is 「獨」.

---

「獨」 is made up of semantic 「犬・犭」 (*dog > beast*) and phonetic 「蜀」 (Mandarin Pinyin: **shǔ**, [Li Fang-Kuei OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Li_(1971)): **/*djuk/**), originally representing the name of a mythical beast. From the [*Classic of Mountains and Seas: Classic of the Mountains: North*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_of_Mountains_and_Seas#Contents):

> #### 《山海經・北山經・北次二經》
>
> ……曰北嚻之山，無石，其陽多碧，其陰多玉。有獸焉，其狀如虎，而白身犬首，馬尾彘鬛，名曰獨。……
>
> ...*It is called the Mountain of* 北嚻. *This mountain is without boulders; its southern side is abundant with green jade, and its northern side is abundant with nephrite. There is a beast in this mountain, shaped like a tiger with a white body; it has the head of a dog, tail of a horse, and neck-bristles of a boar. Its name is* 「獨」...
>
> [image: 獨]

「獨」 were two characters created specifically to represent the name of this beast (Mandarin Pinyin: **dú gǔ**, Li Fang-Kuei OC: **/*duk kuk/**), which consists of two [reduplicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication) syllables.

---

The meaning *alone, solitary* for the character 「獨」 is a [rebus borrowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus#Rebus_principle) for this word; there were other borrowed characters for this word in the pre-[Qín](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) era, most prominently

- 「蜀」 itself;
- 「鹿」

---

**References**:

- 《王力古漢語字典》
- [先秦甲骨金文簡牘詞彙資料庫](https://inscription.asdc.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [小學堂上古音](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/shangguyin)